# Power Series of Function simplified vs unsimplified

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

Find the power series representation of $xe^{2x+1}$.

I first found $e^x$ which is $1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}...$

So then $e^{2x+1}$ is $1+(2x+1)+\frac{(2x+1)^2}{2}+\frac{(2x+1)^3}{6}...$

And thus $xe^{2x+1}$ is $x+x(2x+1)+\frac{x(2x+1)^2}{2}....$

However, this is wrong and the answer is $ex+\frac{e(2x)^2}{2}+\frac{e(2x)^3}{6}$...

I see how they got that, they just brought down the one to make $exe^{2x}$.

Why is my answer wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When they say find a power series expansion, they mean they want you to find the power series about the point zero. If you don't know what it means to find a power series **about a point**, say $x_0$, then this just means finding a power series of the form $$a_0+a_1(x-x_0)+a_2(x-x_0)^2+a_3(x-x_0)^3+...$$ 
What you have found is something of a mix between a power series about the point $-\frac{1}{2}$ (the $(2x+1)$ terms) and about $0$. You'll also notice that if you expand some of your brackets, you'll get extra terms which contribute to the lower-power-of-x terms, e.g. $(2x+1)^2=4x^2+\underbrace{4x+1}_{\text{these ones}}$.

So your power series also represents the same function, and summing all these extra terms would get you to the same answer as the one given. However they implicitly want you to find a power series of the form $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+...$, and so the method they use with bringing down the $e$ is the best way to do it.

Comment: OHHHH!! THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: Haha, no problem :)